# PHP, Mysql sub query with where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query that display all my CLASS details, now I want a sub query that will count all enrolled student in that class.

I tried using two separate query and trying to merge them but I'm not successful doing so.

This is my query so far:

```
$str = "SELECT
                class.id,
                class.code AS classcode,
                section.name AS sectionname,
                subject.code,
                class.units,
                sched.name AS schedule,
                class.slots,
                class.dissolved,
                (SELECT
                    Count(enrolldet.enrollno)
                    FROM
                    enrolldet
                    Inner Join enroll ON enrolldet.enrollno = enroll.enrollno
                    Inner Join class ON enrolldet.class = class.id
                    WHERE
                    enroll.validated =  '1' AND
                    class.id =  class.id) AS enrolled
            FROM
                class 
                Left Join sched ON class.sched = sched.id
                Left Join section ON class.section = section.id
                Left Join subject ON class.subject = subject.id
            ";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $str = "SELECT
                c.id,
                c.code AS classcode,
                section.name AS sectionname,
                subject.code,
                c.units,
                sched.name AS schedule,
                c.slots,
                c.dissolved,
                (SELECT
                    Count(e.enrollno)
                    FROM
                    enrolldet AS e
                    Inner Join enroll ON e.enrollno = enroll.enrollno
                    Inner Join class ON e.class = class.id
                    WHERE
                    enroll.validated =  '1' AND
                    class.id =  c.id) as enrolled
            FROM
                class AS c
                Left Join sched ON c.sched = sched.id
                Left Join section ON c.section = section.id
                Left Join subject ON c.subject = subject.id";
```

i got the correct answer using this. for future reference. i just added aliases for each table

Comment: If you'd like future readers to benefit from your answer, please consider adding an explanation as to what you did, why it wasn't working before and why it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the `class` table of both the main query and the subquery named `class`, because the subquery has access to both tables and this results in the `SQL` engine being confused due to the ambiguity.

To fix your query, give an alias, like `cls`, the inner one and change the `AND` clause to:

```sql
AND `class`.`id` = `cls`.`id`
```

Also, note that your subquery can be simplified by removing the inner `class` table altogether, since the subquery can access the `class` table of the main query, as already mentioned.

**Code:**

```sql
SELECT
   `class`.`id`,
   `class`.`code` AS `classcode`,
   `section`.`name` AS `sectionname`,
   `subject`.`code`,
   `class`.`units`,
   `sched`.`name` AS `schedule`,
   `class`.`slots`,
   `class`.`dissolved`,
   (
      SELECT COUNT(`enrollno`)
      FROM `enrolldet`
      INNER JOIN `enroll`
      ON `enrolldet`.`enrollno` = `enroll`.`enrollno`
      WHERE `enroll`.`validated` = '1'
      AND `enrolldet`.`class` = `class`.`id`
   ) AS `enrolled`
FROM `class`
LEFT JOIN `sched` ON `class`.`sched` = `sched`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `section` ON `class`.`section` = `section`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `subject` ON `class`.`subject` = `subject`.`id`
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all those joins in the subquery.  This should suffice:

```
           (SELECT Count(*)
            FROM enrolldet ed JOIN
                 enroll e
                 ON ed.enrollno = e.enrollno
            WHERE e.validated =  1 AND
                  ed.class = c.id
           ) AS enrolled
```

That is, you don't need `class` in the subquery.  And, I'm guessing that `validated` is a number so I removed the single quotes around "1".